# Get Binded Object of TreeViewItem On Expand

Tags: c#, wpf

I got this `TreeView`:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeViewSL" FontSize="14" Margin="6,65,318,4" TreeViewItem.Selected="TreeViewItem_Selected" TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewItem_Expanded"  Grid.RowSpan="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Name="tbDoc" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Text="&#xe022;"  Padding="2" Style="{StaticResource tbDocStyle}" Visibility="{Binding HasDocs, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
                <TextBlock Name="tbPart" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Text="&#xe006;" Style="{StaticResource tbPartStyle}" Padding="2" Visibility="{Binding ET, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeText}" ></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"/>
        <Style TargetType="ToolTip" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToolTip}}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF5DD5F0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF3266A0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

I use LazyLoad so that the items get loaded at expand, i already got a function like this:

```
private void TreeViewItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var senderItem = e.OriginalSource as ArtikelTreeNode;
}
```

what i want is to give me the item back as binded object, now this give me only null back,
i already tried with: `treeviewsl.Selecteditem as ArtikelTreeNode`, this works but the method `Expanded` gets fired before selected, so i always get the last node...

How i get back the item as object i binded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void TreeViewItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem tvi = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
    var senderItem = tvi.DataContext as ArtikelTreeNode;
}
```

Comment: i got back sender is null

Comment: That's because you hook up the event handlers on the TreeView. Try e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem.